# Angular Jasmine spy throws error randomly in unrelated test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to unit test my Angular component using Jasmine. I have a spec that tests whether an error gets thrown if the TrackService service returns an error (`should throw if TrackService can't get track`). Whenever I run these unit tests using `ng test` all tests usually pass, but sometimes the `Error!` string gets thrown in an unrelated test, for example:

[image: Error thrown in unrelated test]

To me, it seems like the trackServiceSpy object isn't properly 'reset' between tests. How do I make sure the `trackServiceSpy.getTrack` spy doesn't return the error in an unrelated test?

I've also noticed this only happens when the `run tests in random order` setting is enabled in the Jasmine GUI. Otherwise, the tests work fine.

This is my component:

```js
import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { TrackService } from '../../../services/track/track.service';
import { Track } from '../../../models/Track';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-track-list-row',
  templateUrl: './track-list-row.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./track-list-row.component.scss'],
})
export class TrackListRowComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() track: Track | undefined;
  @Output() trackChanged = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() trackCreationCancelled = new EventEmitter<Track>();
  editable = false;
  errors: Record<string, string> = {};
  @ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef | undefined;

  constructor(
    private readonly trackService: TrackService,
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.track?.id) {
      this.getTrack();
    } else {
      this.editTrack();
    }
  }

  onEnter(): void {
    if (this.track) {
      this.saveTrack();
    }
  }

  saveTrack(): void {
    if (this.track) {
      if (this.track.id) {
        this.putTrack();
      } else {
        this.postTrack();
      }
    }
  }

  postTrack(): void {
    if (this.track) {
      this.trackService.addTrack(this.track).subscribe(
        () => {
          this.cancelEdit();
          this.trackChanged.emit();
        },
        (errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.errors = errorResponse.error;
        }
      );
    }
  }

  putTrack(): void {
    if (this.track?.id) {
      this.trackService.putTrack(this.track.id, this.track).subscribe(
        () => {
          this.cancelEdit();
          this.trackChanged.emit();
        },
        (errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.errors = errorResponse.error;
        }
      );
    }
  }

  cancelSaveTrack(): void {
    if (this.track?.id) {
      this.cancelEdit();
    } else {
      this.trackCreationCancelled.emit();
    }
  }

  editTrack(): void {
    this.editable = true;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    if (this.input) {
      this.input.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }

  cancelEdit(): void {
    this.editable = false;
    this.getTrack();
  }

  deleteTrack(): void {
    if (this.track?.id && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      this.trackService.deleteTrack(this.track.id).subscribe(
        () => {
          this.trackChanged.emit();
        },
        (error) => {
          throw `Cannot delete this track. Server response: ${error}`;
        }
      );
    }
  }

  getTrack(): void {
    if (this.track?.id) {
      this.trackService.getTrack(this.track.id).subscribe(
        (track) => {
          this.track = track;
        },
        (error) => {
          throw `Cannot fetch this track. Server response: ${error}`;
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

and here are the related unit tests so far:

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TrackListRowComponent } from './track-list-row.component';
import { TrackService } from '../../../services/track/track.service';
import { Track } from '../../../models/Track';
import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('TrackListRowComponent', () => {
  let component: TrackListRowComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TrackListRowComponent>;
  let trackServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<TrackService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    trackServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('TrackService', [
      'getTracks',
      'getTrack',
      'addTrack',
      'putTrack',
      'deleteTrack',
    ]);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TrackListRowComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule],
      providers: [{ provide: TrackService, useValue: trackServiceSpy }],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TrackListRowComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    const track: Track = new Track(1);
    component.track = track;

    trackServiceSpy.getTrack.and.returnValue(of(track));
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should get track if track id has a value', () => {
    const track: Track = new Track(1);
    component.track = track;

    trackServiceSpy.getTrack.and.returnValue(of(track));

    component.getTrack();

    expect(trackServiceSpy.getTrack).toHaveBeenCalledWith(track.id!);
  });

  it("should throw if TrackService can't get track", () => {
    const track: Track = new Track(1);
    component.track = track;

    trackServiceSpy.getTrack.and.returnValue(throwError('Error!'));
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.getTrack).toThrow();

    component.getTrack();

    expect(trackServiceSpy.getTrack).toHaveBeenCalledWith(track.id!);
  });

  it('should call addTrack from TrackService if track is posted', () => {
    const track: Track = new Track(1);
    component.track = track;

    trackServiceSpy.getTrack.and.returnValue(of(track));
    trackServiceSpy.addTrack.and.returnValue(of(track));

    component.postTrack();

    expect(trackServiceSpy.getTrack).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```